# mex vector<int> values from rhs

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv, vector, mex

I am trying to pass Matlab values to `groupRectangles()` function of opencv using mex.

I need the input parameters as vector of integers and a vector of double. I am using mexopencv's mxArray.cpp.

Using the approach

```
  vector<int> rejectLevels(rhs[1].toVector<int>());
  vector<double> scores(rhs[2].toVector<double>());
```

I believe only returns the first element (the values returned after function also changes everytime I execute), so I believe I need to somehow populate this entry with the Matlab array elements. I don't know C++ so I would appreciate the guidance !

Comment: According to [`groupRectangles` documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html#grouprectangles), it needs a `vector<Rect>` and a `vector<int>`.  Also, where do you convert to a `MxArray`?  This is not the same as MATLAB's `mxArray` that you get via `mexFunction`'s input argument.

Comment: Yes, I didn't include the rectangles part because it is already written by mexopencv. They have a mex to call the function with 3 parameters only (here:https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv/blob/v2.4/src/%2Bcv/groupRectangles.cpp) but I want to be able to call the one with 5 parameters as documented in original opencv code. The mxArray is provided here: https://github.com/kyamagu/mexopencv/blob/v2.4/src/MxArray.cpp

I think I see what you mean with me converting to MxArray however I am not sure how to do that for vector<int> and also assign the values I send from Matlab.

Comment: Okay, I think you mave meant this part: MxArray, I do convert it before those lines, vector<MxArray> rhs(prhs,prhs+nrhs);
    vector<Rect> rectList(MxArray_toVectorRect(rhs[0]));